# Как зарезервировать ip-адрес за VPN-клиентом на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, dhcp

Возможно ли зарезервировать ip-адрес за VPN-клиентом?
MAC-адрес клиента не виден.

Что имеется:

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x64
- VPN-сервер (L2TP)
- SSH доступ

Решение:

> В Ubuntu резервация ip-адреса для VPN-клиента находится в файле /etc/ppp/chap-secrets.
>
> Пример резервирования ip-адреса в chap-secrets:
>
> Пользователь - тип подключения (видимо) - пароль - выделяемый ip
> "user" l2tpd "password" 192.168.42.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используешь /etc/ppp/chap-secrets, то пиши адрес 4ым параметром

```
sklad1 * secret 192.168.12.125
sklad2 * secret *
sklad3 * secret *
```

Если радиус, то там также ip привязывается к логину.

Comment: Привет. Я ничего не использую, просто взял VPS-сервер с VPN-сервером, чтобы обойти мой серый ip на ноутбуке. Только сегодня разобрался (и то не до конца) с iptables и портами входящими. Остался вопрос с резервацией ip-адреса на локального клиента. На Ubuntu-сервере работает DHCP-сервер какой-то, т.к. ip же раздаются. Только я не разбираюсь, как его найти и как настроить. И не особо понимаю, как VPN получает MAC-адрес ноутбучной сетевухи и получает ли вообще или просто раскидывает рандомно ip-адреса клиентам.

Comment: ip раздаются не по dhcp, а по IPCP. MAC адрес не передается - IP привязывается к логину. Логины пароли для впн где создаешь - добавь пару скриншотов с настройками в вопрос.

Comment: Да, действительно файл /etc/ppp/chap-secrets решил проблему.
Поменял в конце учётки * на ip-адрес и всё завелось, как надо.

Пользователь - тип подключения (видимо) - пароль - выделяемый ip.
"user" l2tpd "password" 192.168.42.10

Comment: Не тип подключения, а имя сервиса, устанавливается в options файле. Если вопрос решён, то можно поставить галочку

Comment: Благодарствую, галочку поставил!

Answer (score 0):

делается по именам. Назначение статических IP-адресов клиентам OpenVPN состоит в добавлении строки ifconfig-push <IP-адрес клиента> <IP-адрес сервера> в файлы конфигурации клиентов, которые содержат команды, выполняемые сервером при подключении клиентов, и находятся обычно в папке /etc/openvpn/ccd. Подробнее [документация на сайте openVPN](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Concepts-Addressing)

Comment: У автора вопроса явно не OpenVPN

Comment: мда, лоханулся, не заметил

Comment: andreymal, да, там вроде pluto или как-то так, я пока не разобрался, т.к. новичок в лине

Comment: maint, pluto (vpn) вроде или как-то

Comment: Проблема решена. Файл /etc/ppp/chap-secrets и замена * возле юзера на нужный ip